# Can't access global array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a global variable say :

```
var series,hours;
var loadData = function(){
series = [[]];
hours = [];
d3.json("data/radar.json", function(error, data) {

    data.QualitySummaryObject.forEach(function(d,i) {
        series[i] = d.extractPercentage;
        hours[i] = d.extractorName;
  });


});  
console.log(hours);
};
```

Now if I am trying to access this console.log its working fine, but.

```
var print = function(){
    console.log(hours); //here its not working no value in hours why ... ?
}
```

Comment: where are you calling print?

Comment: use `hours = []` instead of `var hours`. remove `var` from declaration and `hours` will become global

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you `hours` is global:

```
window.hours = [];
```

Then anywhere you can log it:

```
console.log(window.hours);
```

Using directly var without declaration will avoid context problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the above code in a function, the variable `hours` is *not* a global variable because you previously declared it with `var`.

If you want to declare a variable as a global variable, instead of this:

```
var hours = [];
```

Do this:

```
hours = [];
```

To declare a global variable, all you have to do is give it a name.

Comment: no i am not running in any function... var hours is declared outside of every function....

Comment: @SaurabhSinha either way, you should not need to declare a global variable with `var` outside of all the functions.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: Why not? Even global variables can (and should) be declared.

Comment: @Bergi Didn't know that! I thought that global variables in javascript  were declared without `var`.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: It's just that everything without a `var` and no declaration is considered to be global.